# What is the difference between Floating point 16 and 8 bit quantized in Deep Learning Model

Tags: tensorflow, model

Currently, I am reading this website to understand the Face Detection Models. In this article, it mentioned about the **Floating Point 16** and **8 bit quantized** version model.

I would like to ask:

1. What is the difference between two of them?
2. What is the application of different types of DL model? In which case that we need to use ?

Link to website:
https://www.learnopencv.com/face-detection-opencv-dlib-and-deep-learning-c-python/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- What is the difference between two of them?

  As you can see, the model size with 8-bit is smaller than the FP16 one, FP16 and 8-bit here means the precision and type of the model weight values.
- What is the application of different types of DL model? In which case
  that we need to use ?

  Normally high precision will make the model size big but may be more accurate, however, in some case when we need to run the model with small latency or on light-weight device, we may want to reduce the model size with some slight lost of accuracy some times.